# How to blend python into angular Js

Tags: python, angularjs, django

i am having trouble putting python tags in angular js, I just wanted to create a loop. This is my code.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var expandCollapseApp = angular.module('actinbox.web', ['ngAnimate']);

 expandCollapseApp.controller('expandCollapseCtrl', function ($scope) {
    {% for task in taskList %}
       $scope.{{ task.db.id }} = true;
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

I am expected to have this result.

```
$scope.0001 = true;
$scope.0002 = true;
$scope.0003 = true;
$scope.0004 = true;
```

Comment: What isn't working? Why not just make an array?

Comment: I wish I knew how to apply array on this but I am just new to python and angularJs

Comment: This is too broad. My recommendation is to strictly fetch data with angular from the django/python back-end using an ajax request which would provide data in json format. You are using the frameworks in a dangerous way (bug-wise).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in js lie this,

```
for (var task in taskList) {
    var scope_variable = task.db.id;
    var model = $parse(scope_variable);
    model.assign($scope, true);

console.log($scope.0001);  // logs true
```

or if you want use django template tag , you need to use in front itself ..

django and angular both using this {{}}

but the difference is,

if you want to use angular you need to do inside `{% verbatim %}` {{your angular scope}} `{% end verbatim %}`

after `{% end verbatim %}` your django template tag will works

Comment: `taskList` is a django context variable so you can't iterate over it with a javascript (client side) loop

Comment: I suggest some method in js itself.. but u can send it as json from django and use the same in this method. likewise use that django context in html itself with the help of django template